# JSR223 PostProcessor error logs due to same json path in previous multiple response model

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have seen below error in the logs in `JSR223 PostProcessor` despite the script running successfully and the Jmeter steps having no issues.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'result' on null object
```

My JSR223 PostProcessor - groovy 3.0.7 script looks like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

String json = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json);
    
def C_accountNumber = root.myAccount.result[0].accountNumber;

vars.put("C_accountNumber", C_accountNumber);
```

The response just above the above script

```
{
    "myAccount": {
        "result": [
            {
                "accountNumber": "Something",
                "accountAddress": "Something",
             }
          ]
       }
}
```

However, the thing I noticed was, well before the above script in multiple previous step responses also I see below path. (exactly same path `myAccount.result[0]` )

So I am guessing this caused the issue because as one of the previous responses, I can't see `accountNumber` despite having `myAccount.result[0]`.

e.g.

```
{
    "myAccount": {
        "result": [
            {
                "country": "Something",
                "address": "Something",
             }
          ]
       }
}
```

Because this part `String json = prev.getResponseDataAsString();` in the groovy script go through all the previous responses but NOT just immediate before. Is my understanding correct?

Is there way to get rid of these errors in the log?

Comment: Your post processor should be defined as a child of the HTTP request

Comment: @user7294900 that was the issue. Thanks heaps. pl add as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post processor should be defined as a child of the HTTP request

JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#postprocessors) is execute in scope, for specific HTTP request add it as a child of the request

> Post-Processor executes some action after a Sampler Request has been made. If a Post-Processor is attached to a Sampler element, then it will execute just after that sampler element runs.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

If you put the [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) at the same level as several [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to **all of them**

[image]

So if you want to execute the PostProcessor after a certain sampler only - you need to make the PostProcessor a child of the particular Sampler:

[image]